# Java: Using a key from the ProductID HashMap, update the count of the purchases of this product

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

Should update the entry with key 5020 in products map increasing the count of purchases by 2.

I am not sure how to use ProductID.put to make the necessary changes to the entry for the Sales.txt file I have. The file's content displays perfectly but I have no idea how to update the file with the change.

I think I need use iterator at some point. but I am not familiar with HashMap.

```
public class StoreSales {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Customer> customer = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        readFile("Sales.txt", customer);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(customer);

}

public static void readFile(String file, List<Customer> cust) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Map<Integer, Customer> CustomerID = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Customer> ProductID = new HashMap<>();
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] arr = line.split(" ");
            cust.add(new Customer(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), arr[1], arr[2], Integer.parseInt(arr[3]), arr[4], Double.parseDouble(arr[5]), Integer.parseInt(arr[6])));

            if (CustomerID.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]))) {
                CustomerID.get(arr[0]).getSingleItemPrice();

            }
            if (ProductID.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(arr[3]))) {
                ProductID.get(arr[3]).getItemsPurchased();
                **this is the problem** //ProductID.put(, 2++);


            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You are never putting anything in either of the maps (CustomerID, ProductID). Maps are always **empty**

Comment: ProductID is a map of Integer and Customer. What is this Customer class looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the object from the map will give you a reference to the object that you can manipulate.

```
Customer c = ProductID.get(arr[3]);
c.setItemsPurchased(c.getItemsPurchased() + 2);
```

But like Nishit pointed out in the comments the if statements will always be false because you never put anything in the maps.